# Chrome error : Resource requests whose URLs contained both removed whitespace (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I uploaded my website using filezilla to my web host and on firefox it all works fine but on chrome it loads elements partially something has color something has style but I cannot find what exactly is the problem.

I researched and found out that this is a common problem but everyone was getting this inside 1 script or code, I don't have any place to look at because console is just showing the warning :

> "Resource requests whose URLs contained both removed whitespace (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`) characters and less-than characters (`<`) are blocked. Please remove newlines and encode less-than characters from places like element attribute values in order to load these resources."

but I can't find where is the problem, it is my webhost the problem(awardspace.com) or something. I dont know where to look for the mistake.

Here's the website: http://hazardcollective.atwebpages.com

Comment: You have a strange stylesheet url in your head: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css?ts=<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  filemtime() [<a href='function.filemtime'>function.filemtime</a>]: stat failed for main.css in <b>/srv/disk1/3027527/www/hazardcollective.atwebpages.com/index.html</b> on line <b>30</b><br />
" />`

Answer (score 2):

Hy, this error is raised in chrome as a protection feature aganist injection attacks, most of the times its due to missing or unclosed tags for attributes with submitteable data, for instance.. <input class="input  >.. .  The class is not closed and therfore during sending of requests to   the server, it will include all other html content  till another " which closes the class attribute  is found, so first check your html near submitteable fields and make sure its all closed,
See more here : [www.chromestatus.com/feature/5735596811091968](http://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5735596811091968)